# Help with finding a flaw in argument simulating large Turing machines with smaller ones

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

I have an argument which, if it goes through, just about proves that either:

- Programming languages are more powerful than Turing machines
- The busy beaver function ($BB()$) on Turing machines is computable

Now, I understand that it's vastly more likely that my argument has some flaw that I can't find.  But it's more interesting to me *how* I'm wrong, rather than *whether* I'm wrong.

## Argument

Construct a Turing machine $M_1$ as which takes as arguments (on the tape) $n, k$, simulates all Turing machines with $n$ states until $k$ of them halt, and then halts itself.  This is easy to write in a programming language, as demonstrated by the following Python snippet:

```
def M1(n, k):
    all_machines = generate_turing_machines(n)
    is_halted = [0] * len(generate_turing_machines)
    while sum(is_halted) < k:
        for (i, machine) in enumerate(all_machines):
            machine.step()
            if machine.is_halted():
                is_halted[i] = 1
```

Now, let $m_1$ be the number of states required by $M_1$.  Fix $n$ much greater than $m_1$.  Let $k_1$ be the largest number such that $M_1(n, k_1)$ halts and $k_0$ be the smallest number such that when $M_1(n, k_0)$ halts, $k_1$ simulated Turing machines have halted (as all equivalent machines will halt on the same step).  Choose $k$ with $k_0\leq k\leq k_1$.  This means that $M_1(n,k)$ halts in about $BB(n)$ steps.

Construct $M_2$ which is the same as $M_1$ except the first thing it does is write $n$ and $k$ to the tape.  Let $m_2$ be the number of states required by $M_2$.  Then $m_1+K(n)+K(k)+C=m_2$ for some small $C$ (which is probably constant and likely $0$), with $K(n)$ being the Kolmogorov complexity of $n$ in Turing machine states.

Now, $K(n)$ is at most $O(\log(n))$.  There are about $n^n$ machines with $n$ states, so $k$ is about $n^n$, and thus $K(k)$ is at most $O(\log(n^n))=O(n \cdot \log(n))$.  That means that $m_2>n$.  But here we have a problem: if $k$ is easier to write to the tape (so that $K(k)<n-\log(n)$), then $m_2$ would be slightly smaller than $n$.  That would mean $BB(m_2)>BB(n)$ and $m_2<n$, a clear contradiction.

In my mind, these are the possible resolutions:

- $M_1$ is impossible to create as a Turing machine, meaning that Python is more powerful than Turing machines are.
- There is some transfinite extension to Turing machines which is not much more powerful than Turing machines in general, and $M_1$ can be written in this extension.  In other words, $M_1$ is the limit of a set of machines $M_{1,N}$, each of which can handle any $n<N$.  This would probably entail the busy beaver function being computable.
- There is a large set of numbers which cannot be written by a Turing machine in much fewer than $\log(k)=n$ states (we need $K(k)<n-\log(n)$).  It seems impossible to me that no candidate for $(n, k)$ could be sufficiently compressed.

Where is the error in this logic?

---

I had previously said that $K(k)\leq O(n)$, but @6005 pointed out that was suspect.  With that fixed (to $O(n \cdot \log(n))$), it still seems very surprising to me that we can't achieve a reduction from $K(k)\approx n \cdot \log(n)$ to $K(k)<n-\log(n)$ for any potential value of $(n,k)$, but no longer inconceivable.

Comment: Your argument just shows that busy beaver numbers have high Kolmogorov complexity (your last option). Your machine $M_1$ can be easily implemented as a Turing machine. There’s absolutely no contradiction, only to your intuition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, those aren't busy beaver numbers.  $k$ represents the number of machines with $n$ states which halt.  There isn't any reason in particular why those numbers would have high Kolmogorov complexity, especially since (depending on the enumeration) there are a large number of equivalent machines and thus a large number of equivalent consecutive $k$s which would all need high Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Your argument might be less confusing if you wrote it down using Kolmogorov complexity rather than your $\mathbb S$ measure.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I edited it to be that way (it is probably clearer, you're right, but it's at most a notational difference).

Comment: I do not understand the definition of $k_0$. Please make it more precise (and formal).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Suppose $M_1(n, k_1)$ halts in $x$ steps.  Then there exists a $k_0\leq k_1$ such that $M_1(n, k_0)$ halts in $x$ steps but $M_1(n, k_0 - 1)$ halts in fewer than $x$ steps.  We can say $k_0<k_1$ because in some enumerations of Turing machines there are many equivalent machines (up to order of states, etc.).  Does that explain it?

Comment: @AndrejBauer If I understood it correctly, while $k_1$ is the number of machines with $n$ states that halt, if there are $u$ machines that halt in the maximum number of steps,  then $k_0 = k_1 - u + 1$. This is the minimum number such that if you feed it into the algorithm M1, M1 will terminate with all $k_1$ machines halting.

Comment: @Spitemaster As for your post, everything is clear prior to the paragraph beginning "Now, $K(n)$ is at most O(log(n))". However that paragraph is less than clear, and all based on intuition and heuristics. What you should do is put some time into formalizing this paragraph; in particular, how exactly are you choosing $n$ and $k$? Your argument that $k$ has kolmogorov complexity $O(n)$ seems particularly suspect, as $k$ is some arbitrary, uncomputable number that you don't get to control (and  just the fact that $k$ is between $k_0$ and $k_1$ doesn't give much flexibility).

Comment: @6005 Ah, you're right! $O(n)$ is incorrect - I should have put $O(n*log(n))$ which is less unbelievable.  I've made some improvements.

Comment: @Spitemaster Yes I see that seems to be the problem as well. I have written an answer based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flaw seems to be here:

> Now, $K(n)$ is at most $O(\log(n))$.  $k$ is about $n^n$, so $K(k)$ is at most $O(n)$.  That puts $m_2$ just slightly larger than $n$.

It's true that $k$ is about $n^n$ (more precisely, $k = n^{\Theta(n)}$ or $k = 2^{\Theta(n \log n)}$, and this can be shown by upper bounding $k$ by the number of Turing machines, and lower bounding by finding a family of simple halting Turing machines). However, that doesn't imply that $K(k)$ is at most $O(n)$.
Rather, we only know that $K(k)$ is at most
$$
O(\log(n^n)) = O(n \log n).
$$

Your contradiction relies on picking $k$ so that $K(k)$ is $o(n)$ (a bit smaller than $n$). Your reasoning shows that this is impossible.

But this is not too surprising: most $k$ we expect to be about $O(n \log n)$, and $k$ is a number that holds a lot of information about Turing machines with $n$ states, so we don't expect to be able to compress such a number to smaller than $O(n)$ states itself.

---

**P.S.** Putting aside the question of whether Python is really equivalent to Turing machines (probably no one knows, as it hasn't been formally shown), your program `M1` is in fact clearly expressible as a Turing machine. From this, you should be able to see that the resolutions based on `M1` not being expressible as a Turing machine are not correct.

Comment: A very small fragment of Python, which can easily be formalized, is quite clearly Turing complete, so I wouldn't worry about that.